# Why do some sequences of remainders not repeat immediately?

Tags: number-theory

I was looking into the cyclicity of remainders and stumbled upon this example: The remainder sequence of $2^n$ mod $28$ is $(2, 4, 8, 16, 4, 8, 16,...)$.

I noticed that before the repeating sequence $(4, 8, 16, 4, 8, 16,...)$ begins, there is a term $2$ that precedes it. Other examples such as $2^n$ mod $48$ showed the same too $(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 16, 32,...)$.

I know this has something to do with Euler's theorem and how $2$ shares factors with $28$ and $48$, but was looking for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: The easiest example for this behaviour is $ 2^n mod 4. (2,0,0,0,0,0,...) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $a$ shares a common factor $p$ with $n$. Consider $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots \pmod n$. Let's assume that $a$ does repeat in this infinite list after the first occurrence (unlike in your example, where it doesn't repeat). We thus have $a = a^k \pmod n$ for some $k > 1$. This means that $a^k - a$ is divisible by $n$. Let $p^u$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$. Since it divides $n$, and $n$ divides $a^k-a$, $p^u$ must divide $a^k-a$ as well. But $a^k - a = a(a^{k-1}-1)$. Since $p$ divides $a$, it must divide $a^{k-1}$ (as $k > 1$), so it cannot divide $a^{k-1} - 1$. Thus $p^u$ must divide $a$ as well. In short, if $a$ repeats in the infinite list of powers $\pmod n$, then each prime factor shared by $a$ and $n$ must divide $a$ in at least the same power as it divides $n$.

In your example, $a = 2$, $p = 2$, $n = 28$, however, $4 = 2^2$ divides $28$, but $2^2$ does not divide $2$, so $a = 2$ cannot repeat in $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots \pmod n$.